# What to Set in StatusCallback on an outbound call if the application running locally

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I have created my application with NODE.JS . I am running my application locally . I want to Monitor outbound call events.
As I am running my application locally , what I have to Set in StatusCallback on an outbound call.

I am using this code snippet.

```
    const accountSid = 'your_accountSid';
    const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
    const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls
      .create({
         method: 'GET',
         statusCallback: '',
         statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
         url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
         to: '+14155551212',
         from: '+18668675310'
       })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We recommending using a tunnelling program to give your local development server a public URL. My favourite is [ngrok](https://ngrok.com), check out this post on [how to use ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) and if you use VS Code, I also wrote a [plugin to make it easy to use ngrok in VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=philnash.ngrok-for-vscode).